# Homework, want to solve with Prolog

Tags: prolog

Can I solve the homework for my logic class with Prolog?

```
5 people are interrogated. The statements from A and B are lost.
C says: If A is truthful then B is truthful.
D says: If C is truthful then A is truthful.
E says: If D is truthful then A is truthful.

1) Is it possible that C lies?
2) Is it possible that D lies? 
3) Is it possible that E lies?
```

My latest attempt was

```
f(A, B, C, D, E):-
    (C->(A->B)),
    (D->(C->A)),
    (E->(A->D)).
```

This compiles, but when I query Prolog with

```
f(A, B, C, D, E).
```

I get the error "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated".

Comment: I corrected 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can model with:

```
stat(truth).
stat(lies).

go(A, B, C, D, E) :-
    maplist(stat, [A, B, C, D, E]),
    stat_if(C, A, B),
    stat_if(D, C, A),
    stat_if(E, D, A).

stat_if(truth, A, B) :-
    implies(A, B).
stat_if(lies, A, B) :-
    \+ implies(A, B).

implies(truth, truth).
% If lying, cannot determine
implies(lies, _).
```

Then run with e.g.:

```
?- go(A, B, C, D, truth).
A = B, B = C, C = D, D = truth ;
A = D, D = truth,
B = C, C = lies ;
A = D, D = lies,
B = C, C = truth ;
A = B, B = D, D = lies,
C = truth ;
false.

?- go(A, B, C, D, lies).
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I'm a total beginner in Prolog, could you explain it a little? What is "stat_if" for example?
Also, Prolog claims there are 2 solutions to "go(A, B, C, D, lies).", but that is not true:
If E lies then:
(1) E is false.
(2) (D => A) is false, which is equivalent to (D and not A).
(3) Because of D, (not C or A) is true, which is equivalent to (not C) because of (not A) in (2).
(4) Because of (not C), A=>B is false, which is equivalent to (A and not B).
(5) Because of (2), A must be false, and because of (4), A must be true.
Therefore E can't be lying.

Comment: I missed that "stat_if" was defined further below, but I still don't really understand it.
What do "!" and "stat_if(_, _, _)" do?

Comment: Edited - should be closer to the logic you're intending, try that :-)

Comment: Hm, I still get 2 results with "go(A, B, C, D, lies).", I expect 0.

Comment: Should be correct now - I used https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false for inspiration.